# Passar dado de um componente para outro em angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um componente que mostra uma imagem e um outro componente que deve alterar o **src** dessa imagem.

Tentei fazer o seguinte:

**Perfil.component.ts**

```
 alteraDadosPerfil(){

    this.perfilService.alteraDadosPerfil(this.perfil,this.croppedImage)
      .pipe(
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {

        if(this.croppedImage != null){ //Se foi alterado imagem então guarda a foto no localstorage e chama o método do serviço que altera a foto de perfil
          localStorage.setItem('foto', this.croppedImage);
          this.perfilService.alteraFotoPerfil(this.croppedImage);
        }
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      })
    }
```

**Perfil.service.ts**

```
fotoPerfil: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  alteraFotoPerfil(base64Foto: string){
    this.fotoPerfil.next(base64Foto);
  }

Home.component.ts

avatarPerfil: string = null;

 ngOnInit(){

    this.avatarPerfil = localStorage.getItem('foto');
    this.nomeUsuarioLogado = localStorage.getItem('nome');
    this.emailUsuarioLogado = localStorage.getItem('emailUsuario');

    this.perfilService.fotoPerfil.subscribe(res => { //Não está entrando aqui dentro
      this.avatarPerfil = res
   })
  }
```

Comment: Onde você está chamando o método alteraFotoPerfil?

Comment: É em uma função, eu sei que está chegando nessa função porque se eu colocar um console.log('teste') é printado no momento correto, mas por algum motivo o subscribe não recebe a alteração

Comment: Você está usando o Subject?

Comment: Sim, no perfilService eu declarei: fotoPerfil: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

Comment: Será que você não está chamando o unsubscribe em algum lugar antes?

Comment: eu não uso unsubscribe

Comment: Adiciona todo seu código envolvido no problema.

Comment: Em qual módulo está o Service?

Comment: Alterei a pergunta adicionando todo o código

Comment: O serviço é importado e adicionado no providers dos dois módulos (HomeComponent que é o componente que deve receber a foto de perfil e no componente PerfilComponent que deve mandar o dado para o homeComponent)

Comment: Remova o serviço de ambos e coloque somente no providers do módulo raiz da sua aplicação

Comment: Isso funcionou, alguma explicação pra isso? Adicione uma resposta explicando para que eu possa dar como a resposta correta.

Comment: Sim, só um momento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Angular temos o Injector que é responsável por criar o serviço e injetá-lo nos componentes. Todo o serviço é um singleton para o Injector. Quando você adiciona o serviço no módulo principal, você está registrando o serviço no Injector raiz da aplicação, ou seja, há somente um PerfilService para toda a aplicação, todos os componentes irão obter a mesma instância, a não ser que o serviço seja registrado em algum módulo filho ou componente, como o foi o caso do problema mencionado nos comentários, onde cada componente tinha uma instância diferente do serviço.

Recomendo a leitura: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection